# INSERT dentro de um SELECT - SQL Server

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Preciso fazer um INSERT dentro de um SELECT em alguns casos na minha Query.

Um exemplo de como preciso:

```
SELECT IdTabela,
       Nome,
       CASE
         WHEN IdTabela > 10 
           THEN 
             INSERT INTO TabelaExemplo (IdTabelaExemplo) VALUES (IdTabela)
       END
FROM Tabela
```

Eu já procurei varios modos na internet, e um exemplo que achei é esse:

```
INSERT INTO TabelaExemplo 
            (IdTabelaExemplo) 
VALUES      (SELECT IdTabela 
             FROM   Tabela 
             WHERE  IdTabela > 10)
```

Porem esse forma não resolve o meu problema.

Obrigado!

At.
Guilherme

Answer (score 2):

Tenta dessa maneira sem *VALUES*

```
INSERT INTO TabelaExemplo 
    (IdTabelaExemplo)
    SELECT IdTabela FROM Tabela
    WHERE IdTabela > 10
```

Referência: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

Comment: É que dessa forma não funciona no meu caso amigo. Eu precisa de algo bem parecido com o primeiro exemplo... Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Cria uma procedure pra fazer isso, e la dentro voce vai poder fazer a validacao via `SELECT` e com um `IF` decidir se vai ser inserido ou nao.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PROC_INSERE
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @IDTABELA INT

SELECT @IDTABELA  = IdTabela FROM Tabela

if @IDTABELA > 10 
    begin
         INSERT INTO TabelaExemplo (IdTabelaExemplo) VALUES (IdTabela)
    end

END
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma outra maneira de fazer isso seria usando um Cursor:

```
/* 
  Procedimento que serve para:
  incluir registro em uma tabela com base em uma consulta e uma condição 
  Criado em: 08/08/2016
*/

USE Sample1

-- Não exibe alterações
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE 
 @idTabela int,
 @Nome varchar(100) 

DECLARE Incluir_cursor CURSOR FOR
   select
     idTabela, Nome
   from
    Tabela1

-- Inicialização de variáveis
SET @idTabela = 0

OPEN Incluir_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM Incluir_cursor INTO @idTabela, @Nome

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  IF @idTabela > 10
   INSERT INTO TabelaExemplo (IdTabelaExemplo) VALUES (@idTabela)

  -- Vai para o próximo registro
  FETCH NEXT FROM Incluir_cursor INTO @idTabela, @Nome
END

-- Fecha o cursor
CLOSE Incluir_cursor
DEALLOCATE Incluir_cursor

-- Exibe alterações
SET NOCOUNT OFF
```